# Pandas - sort on unique values

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

By grouping my df like so:

```
# set X value
target_x = 'Goals'
# reduce df to target column
df_temp = df_players.set_index("Player")
# get mean value for every player
df_temp[target_x] = df_temp.groupby('Player')[target_x].mean()    
# get values for axis plot
X = df_temp[target_x]
```

I ended up with `X`:

```
Andrew Robertson      0.038462
Dejan Lovren          0.000000
Joel Matip            0.038462
Joseph Gomez          0.000000
Nathaniel Phillips    0.000000
                        ...   
Michail Antonio       0.038462
Nathan Holland        0.000000
Pablo Fornals         0.076923
Robert Snodgrass      0.192308
Tomas Soucek          0.000000
```

Which I would like to sort now.

There are, however, many repeated players (and values), and if I do:

```
X.sort_values(ascending=False).unique()
```

I sort losing reference to players:

```
[0.62962963 0.59259259 0.55555556 0.53846154 0.5        0.48148148
 0.44444444 0.42307692 0.40740741 0.37037037 0.33333333 0.30769231
 0.2962963  0.25925926 0.23076923 0.22222222 0.19230769 0.18518519
 0.15384615 0.14814815 0.11538462 0.11111111 0.07692308 0.07407407
 0.03846154 0.03703704 0.        ]
```

---

So how do I sort keeping track of player for each sorted value?

Comment: do you know of the `by` argument ? you can sort by multiple columns `x.sort_values(['player','mean'])`

Comment: If you are looking for mean values for the players, you can do `X = df_temp.groupby('Player')[target_x].mean()` instead of `X = df_temp[target_x]`. `groupby` produces unique players with their aggregated means, then you can sort the output.

Comment: Use `X.sort_values(ascending=False).drop_duplicates()` instead, `unique` creates an `np.array` which dont have indices.

Comment: @Erfan this works. care to answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `X.sort_values(ascending=False).drop_duplicates()` instead, `unique` creates a `numpy.array` which don't have indices.